# 2 separated objects are connected for some reason

Tags: java

This is my homework(assignment). I really hope someone can help me figure out what I did wrong.

When I tried to create an object of State
state = new State(tablesize, tb);

and then tried to make a copy
State st2 = new State(state);

and then tried to modify the data in state
state.placeNumber(1,1,3);

for some reason, the data in st2 is also changed.

Below is the code. I really hope someone can point out where my mistake is.

Thanks

```
public class State 
{

private int arraysize;
private int lastfilledx;
private int lastfilledy;
private int table[][];

//constructor

    public State()
    {

    }
    public State(State s)
    {
        arraysize = s.getsize();
        lastfilledx = s.lastindex_x();
        lastfilledy = s.lastindex_y();
        table = s.gettable();
    }
    public State(int size, int[][] tb)
    {
        arraysize = size;
        table = new int[size][size];        
        //copy the initial table which is a 2d array
        table = tb;     
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < size ; j++)
            {
                 if ( table[i][j] == 1)
                 {

                    lastfilledx = i; 
                    lastfilledy =j;                   
                    break;
                 }
            }
        }
    }

public void placeNumber(int i, int j, int nextvalue)
{
    lastfilledx = i; 
    lastfilledy = j;    
    table[i][j] = nextvalue;
}   

public void printoutput()
{
        for (int i=0; i < arraysize; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < arraysize; j++)
                System.out.print("  " + table[i][j]);

            System.out.println("");
        }

        System.out.println("last fill " + lastfilledx + " " + lastfilledy);
}

public int[][] gettable()
{
    return table;
}

public int getsize()
{
    return arraysize;
}
public int lastindex_x()
{
    return lastfilledx;
}
public int lastindex_y()
{
    return lastfilledy;
}
}




public class Dikuho extends State
{
    private static State state;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int tablesize = 3;
    int tb[][] = new int[tablesize][tablesize];

    /*****HARDCODE the table data***/
    for (int i=0; i < tablesize; i++)
        for (int j=0; j < tablesize; j++)
            tb[i][j] = 0;


    //test case for 3x3
    tb[2][2] = 1;
    tb[0][0] = tablesize*tablesize;
    tb[0][1] = 7;
    tb[1][0] = 8;
    tb[2][1] = 2;       

    //initialize the state
    state = new State(tablesize, tb);


    **//Here is where the problem is. I only change the data in state but the data in st2 is also changed. I'm not sure what happen here.**
    State st2 = new State(state);   
    state.placeNumber(1,1,3);

    st2.printoutput();    **//These both printout same output which is not correct**    
    state.printoutput();
    }


}
```

Comment: Your objects share the same array of ints

Comment: @benjamin.d is there a reason why you are not posting it as answer?

Comment: Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int) for help making a deep copy.  Don't forget, you have a 2D array and must copy accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructor has made a *shallow copy* of `table` 2D array.  Both the original object and the copy refer to the same original array, because you assign the array reference from the original to the new object.  That's fine for the `int` values, because the values are copied.  But that's not okay for objects, for which references to the obejct are copied.

Instead of just copying the reference to the array...

```
table = s.gettable();
```

You'll need to create a new, copied array:

```
table = new int[arraysize][arraysize];
// 2 nested for loops here to copy the contents
```

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment on the question itself, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int) can help simplify the copying

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[][] gettable()
{
    return table;
}
```

So, both of your state objects are referencing the same array. you need to create a new array for each instance.